# Use of $\curlywedge$ for a void/empty sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, notation

In [*Quantification in Non-Classical Logic*](https://books.google.com/books/about/Quantification_in_Nonclassical_Logic.html?id=RXMzk-ZbC78C&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button#v=onepage&q&f=false), Gabbay et al. use the curly wedge symbol ($\curlywedge$) to denote a void/empty sequence (see page 20 in the Google Books preview; it's introduced on page xviii in the introduction).

Is this an established/common notation? Does anyone know where the notation comes from, assuming it isn't novel to this book?

Comment: I haven't heard of that. Sometimes I've seen a capital lambda ($\Lambda$) for an empty sequence, but that's the closest I've got.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thanks for the input, I wouldn't be surprised if this usage is derivative on the use of capital lambda -- with curly wedge being used as an italicized variant or something of the sort. (It would make sense that they wouldn't want to use $\Lambda$ since they use it as a metavariable for an arbitrary logic.)